# Starting Chevy Cobalt Is taking a Long Time To Turn Over

Tags: starting, chevrolet, cobalt

I have a Chevy Cobalt, that I've noticed is starting to have a difficult time starting. It still can do it, but anymore, it take about 5+ seconds of cranking for it to turn over. It only seems to do this when it has been sitting for a while. If I start it, immediately turn it off, then start it, it turns right over without issue.

I did have the ignition recall fixed a couple years ago.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what this could be?

- Year: 2008
- Miles: 140k
- Motor: 4-cyl 2.4L (I think)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you think is the interval you'd have to wait between when it will start right away and when it takes a bit longer? If you turn the key to the run position, then turn it off, then back on to start, will it start right up? When was the last time the fuel filter was changed?

Comment: I've turned it off almost immediately, and it starts right up. How long before it will take a while to start, I'm not sure. I would have to do some experimentation. It has never been changed in the ten years that I've owned it.

Comment: Fuel filter needs to be changed every so often. It becomes plugged after a while and inhibits the ability of fuel flow through it. If it hadn't been changed in 10 years, it's something I'd highly recommend changing just as a regular maintenance item.